# What is the lowest common ancestor of 5 and 4 in this binary tree

Tags: binary-tree, depth-first-search, lowest-common-ancestor

Binary tree

[image: Binary tree]

What is the lowest common ancestor of 5 and 4 in the binary tree above, considering we allow a node to be a descendant of itself. Wouldn't it be 3? if not, what would it be and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we allow a node to be a descendant of itself, LCA will be 5.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer but i'm trying to understand here, when we say lowest common ancestor, are we talking about the common ancestor lowest in value or lowest in position of the tree?

Comment: Let T be a rooted tree. The lowest common ancestor between two nodes n1 and n2 is defined as the lowest node (considering distance) in T that has both n1 and n2 as descendants.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.